# RabbitMQ consumers Connection refused on managed server. Possible reasons?

Tags: php, linux, symfony, connection, rabbitmq

We are using Symfony 2.2 with the OldSound RabbitMqBundle. A rabbitmq server is running on another instance. The server configuration is fine as everything is working on localhost and messages are sent and retrieved from/by the server. 
On our managed server we get following error by starting a rabbitmq:consumer. This must result from any missing permissions, closed ports or some other circumstances, which are different on the managed server (hetzner) than on the localhost.
Do you have any idea how to analyse or fix this problem?

Executed Command:

```
:~/../app$ php console rabbitmq:consumer -m 100 transfer_data
```

Error message:

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException]
Error Connecting to server(111): Connection refused

rabbitmq:consumer [-m|--messages[="..."]] [-r|--route[="..."]] [-l|--memory-limit[="..."]] [-d|--debug] [-w|--without-signals] name
```

Comment: Did you check the firewall settings, permission, etc (as you mentioned yourself)? What are the results?

Comment: Not yet. What are the requirements to the firewall and permissions?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

Comment: Thank you. We had to open port 5672 for TCP and the IP adress of the rabbitmq server. Working now